# Insert Div in gridview cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and on RowDatabound event i am trying to insert a div inside the cell and set the innerhtml. On debugging the innerHTML of the div is full of text. But when it is run ii is an empty cell. Any help?

```
        protected void grdThreat_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

            div.InnerHtml = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;
            e.Row.Cells[4].Controls.Add(div);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panel will render as a `div`, so you can use this:

```
Panel mainPanel = new Panel();

mainPanel .Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(e.Row.Cells[4].Text));

e.Row.Cells[4].Controls.Add(mainPanel);
```

Comment: hm, it works but My e.row.cells[4].Text contains Html tags like <br> etc. And i can see the <br> in the cell instead of new line.

Comment: Ho, you want otherway around then try
mainPanel.Controls.Add(new Label(e.Row.Cells[4].Text));